# What is the purpose of custom business event component in mule ESB?

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio

I have kept custom business component at the end of flow and added metadata [#payload] but it didn't get logged on screen, then what is the purpose of this component? is there any tracking folder to track this business activity ?

Answer (score 1):

Mule allows to log certain information from the business transaction which is important for the business. e.g. In payment processing flow log transaction ID where transacted amount is >50 Crore.
For more information please refer documentation for [Business event](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/business-events)

You can see those business events on 'Runtime Manager' or Mule Management Console.

Screenshot for Mule Management Console (MMC) for Business Event tab:
[image]

Also refer [use case](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-management-console/v/3.8/business-events-use-cases) for business event.

Comment: Hi Vijay, Does mule provides this Business Tracking window? I'm executing the same example locally, Where can i find this tracking window? is it kind of opensource like register and use like cloud hub is used to run couple of services on cloud temporarily ?

Comment: Nope, this view is a web application to be used with the Enterprise Edition of Mule ESB.

Comment: I have added screenshot for MMC Business event tab. Since you are running locally you must be deploying your app on Mule local runtime manager which is MMC. This feature is also available in community edition and don't have to register anything additional.

Comment: FYI MMC is not for community edition, it's available for enterprise edition